# Laravel 5: Signing e-mail with DKIM

Tags: php, email, laravel, smtp, dkim

In my project I'm trying to send e-mail through my own SMTP server using Laravel 5. I have everything set up correctly using the SMTP driver and I'm managing to send and receive e-mail fine.

I want to get set up using DKIM. I've set up my public key and made it available in my DNS and I have a private key ready to start signing my messages.

However, I can't find any documentation on how to set up DKIM signing using Laravel/Swift Mailer. I've managed to sign my e-mails with DKIM before in another non-Laravel project that used `PHPMailer` but can't find any way of doing it here. I've had a browse through `Illuminate\Mail\Message` and `Illuminte\Mail\Mailer` but can't find anything relevant.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Current example code:

```
public function handle(UserWasRegistered $event)
{
    $user = $event->getUser();

    $this->mailer->send(['emails.users.welcome.html', 'emails.users.welcome.text'], ['user' => $user], function($message) use($user) {
        $message->subject('Welcome to XXXXXX');
        $message->to($user->email);
    });
}
```

Ideally, I would like to be able to provide my DKIM private key in the config somewhere and have Laravel/Swift Mailer (Or write some code once) sign my messages for me.

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

I wrote decorator of MailServiceProvider for Laravel 5 that provides ability to sign outgoing messages with DKIM:

https://github.com/vitalybaev/laravel5-dkim

Answer (score 1):

You have to extend Laravel Mailer and mail service provider. Default laravel mailer using new Swift_Message class not Swift_SignedMessage thats why you don't have options for signing.

Here is a package for [laravel 4](https://github.com/academe/laraveldkim).